# Convert a string into an array based on regex condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, string-matching

Using JavaScript I'm creating a function that can take a string as a parameter and returns an array based on a regex condition. The string contains a pipe or | in certain places and I want to grab the string before the pipe gets iterated. To get a bit more clarity below is the visual representation

For example -

string: `"Material: 100% Polyester | Three-button | Color: Gray"`

resulted Array: `["Material: 100% Polyester", "Three-button", "Color Gray"]`

Let me know if more information is needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `split`

```js
const list = "Material: 100% Polyester | Three-button | Color: Gray"

console.log(list.split(" | "))
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. There were some white space and new line were added to the array elements after applying split method but the .trim() function able to remove all of it